# transparent linear gradient looking strange in safari

Tags: html, css

I have this dotted pattern, where I would like to fade the bottom out. I use a pseudoelement with a linear gradient from transparent to the color of the background.

In firefox it looks good, but in safari (14.1.1) it for some reason looks strange like this

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

```css
        :root {
            --main-color:#05e2ff
        }

        body {
            background-color: var(--main-color);
        }

        .line {
            position:relative;
            margin:0 auto;
            height:50vh;
            width:20px;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 150' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='%2300B4D0'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
        }

        .line::after {
            content:'';
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, var(--main-color));
        }
```

```html
    <div class="line">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`transparent` color keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword) is a shortcut for `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. That means Safari is creating a gradient from transparent black to `--main-color`. As the alpha channel transitions from 0–1, it gets gray, then as the RGB values transition to their values from `--main-color`, it becomes the correct color.

An alternate approach is to use the `mask` property on the `.line` element and get rid of the pseudoelement. (Note that Safari needs `-webkit-mask`, so I’m defining the mask in a custom property and applying to both `mask` and `-webkit-mask` for compatibility.)

```css
:root {
    --main-color:#05e2ff
}

body {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.line {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50vh;
    width:20px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 150' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='%2300B4D0'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
    --mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, transparent);
    mask: var(--mask);
    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
}
```

```html
  <div class="line">

</div>
```